# Как упорядочить элементы в объекте mongodb(mongoose, node.js)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

После присвоения дефолтного значения  элементу объекта `default: false`, при выводе объекта элемент стал отображаться первым

Модель:

```
    example: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: false
    }
```

Как выводится сейчас:

```
    {
        "example": false,
        "_id": "0",
    },
```

Нужно выводить так(до присвоения `default: false`, так и было):

```
    {
        "_id": "0",
        "example": "false",
    },
```

Достаю объект и отдаю на клиент так:

```
const all_example = await Example.find({}, {
                __v: 0
            });
return res.status(200).json(all_example);
```

Вопрос: **"Как упорядочить элементы, чтобы _id был на первом месте?
Есть хорошее решение?"**

Comment: А почему порядок полей в объекте для Вас настолько важен? Затрудняюсь представить реальную ситуацию, в которой это было бы принципиально.

Comment: @Yaant для визуального удобства человека, который будет делать клиент :)
Это как с пользовательскими интерфейсами, если человек привык работать с линуксом, он будет искать крестик слева, если ему придется работать с виндой, первое время будет не комфортно постоянно ошибаться в местоположении крестика. Тут то же самое, человек будет ждать поле id в самом верху, а его там не окажется и он испытает некое неудобство :)

Comment: Ну, поскольку порядок полей в объекте определяется порядком их создания (за некоторыми исключениями), то можно сделать как-нибудь так: `return res.status(200).json({_id : all_example._id, example : all_example.example);`